# PySpark read JSON with custom nested schema doesn't apply

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, nested, pyspark-schema

I have this simple JSON file:

```
{"adas":{"parkAssist":{"rear":{"alarm":false,"muted":false},"front":{"alarm":false,"muted":false}},"lane":{"keepAssist":{"right":false,"left":false}}}}
```

But when I'm trying to read it like this:

```
spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true") \
          .option("multiline", "true") \
          .json(///myfile.json) \
          .first() \
          .asDict()
```

I get:

```
{"adas":{"parkAssist":{"rear":{"alarm":false,"muted":false},"front":{"alarm":false,"muted":false}},"lane":{"keepAssist":{"alarm":false,"muted":false}}}}
```

Which is wrong because `adas_lane_keepAssist` arguments are not correct.

If in source JSON I change one of the `adas_lane_keepAssist` arguments to "true", then the mapping is correct...

I also thought that maybe it's `inferSchema` the root of the problem, so I've made a custom_schema:

```
custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField("adas",StructType([
        StructField("parkAssist",StructType([
            StructField("rear",StructType([
                StructField("alarm",BooleanType(),True),
                StructField("muted",BooleanType(),True)
            ])),
            StructField("front",StructType([
                StructField("alarm",BooleanType(),True),
                StructField("muted",BooleanType(),True)
            ]))
        ])),
        StructField("lane",StructType([
            StructField("keepAssist",StructType([
                StructField("right",BooleanType(),True),
                StructField("left",BooleanType(),True)
            ]))
        ]))
    ]))
  ])
```

and read it like this:

```
spark.read.schema(custom_schema) \
          .option("multiline", "true") \
          .json(///myfile.json) \
          .first() \
          .asDict()
```

And I get the same wrong result:

```
{"adas":{"parkAssist":{"rear":{"alarm":false,"muted":false},"front":{"alarm":false,"muted":false}},"lane":{"keepAssist":{"alarm":false,"muted":false}}}}
```

The funny thing is if I change the order in my `custom_shema` like this:

```
custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField("adas",StructType([
        StructField("lane",StructType([
            StructField("keepAssist",StructType([
                StructField("right",BooleanType(),True),
                StructField("left",BooleanType(),True)
            ]))
        ])),
        StructField("parkAssist",StructType([
            StructField("rear",StructType([
                StructField("alarm",BooleanType(),True),
                StructField("muted",BooleanType(),True)
            ])),
            StructField("front",StructType([
                StructField("alarm",BooleanType(),True),
                StructField("muted",BooleanType(),True)
            ]))
        ]))
    ]))
  ])
```

Now every argument of `adas_parkAssist_front/left` is wrong:

```
{"adas":{"lane":{"keepAssist":{"right":false,"left":false}}, "parkAssist":{"rear":{"right":false,"left":false},"front":{"right":false,"left":false}}}}
```

Is this a limitation of PySpark?

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange to me too. I tried `first`, `head` and `collect`, but they all returned the same distorted structure. Before those lines, if I printed the schema, it was correct. So, the problem is in functions `first`, `head`, `collect` not working correctly with nested structs...

Looking for a workaround, I transformed the whole schema (which was correct after reading the JSON file) to a map type.

```py
df = spark.read.json(r"path\test_file.json")
df = df.withColumn('adas', F.create_map(
    F.lit('lane'), F.create_map(
        F.lit('keepAssist'), F.create_map(
            F.lit('left'), F.col('adas.lane.keepAssist.left'),
            F.lit('right'), F.col('adas.lane.keepAssist.right')
        )
    ),
    F.lit('parkAssist'), F.create_map(
        F.lit('front'), F.create_map(
            F.lit('alarm'), F.col('adas.parkAssist.front.alarm'),
            F.lit('muted'), F.col('adas.parkAssist.front.muted')
        ),
        F.lit('rear'), F.create_map(
            F.lit('alarm'), F.col('adas.parkAssist.rear.alarm'),
            F.lit('muted'), F.col('adas.parkAssist.rear.muted')
        )
    )
))
print(df.head().asDict())
# {'adas': {'lane': {'keepAssist': {'left': False, 'right': False}}, 'parkAssist': {'rear': {'alarm': False, 'muted': False}, 'front': {'alarm': False, 'muted': False}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

My spark version was 3.1.1.

After updating it to 3.2.0, the custom nested schema was read as expected.

Thx !